# @Query in JPA is giving null output for STR TO DATE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

the following query is resulting in null output for all the entries in the resulting list.

```
 @Query(value="select STR_TO_DATE(sp.date,'%d-%m-%Y') from shift_plan sp where sp.date>=:leaveDate and sp.shift_type NOT IN('leaveMorning','leaveAfternoon')",nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Date> findDatesGreaterThanOrEqualToLeaveDate(@Param("leaveDate") Date leaveDate);
```

I have saved the date as Date type in my java code but it has been saved as varchar in my database table shift_plan.I have saved from java as follows

```
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(j + "/" + (month_num + 1) + "/" + year));
                        sp.setDate(cal.getTime());
```

How to get the list of actual dates here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got fixed after changing the datatype of date from varchar to date in database. STR_TO_DATE was not required after that.